# CCDirector may not respond to presentviewcontroller:animation

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, cocos2d-iphone

I'm new in cocoa2d.I'm trying to use presentViewController in view for Facebook Sharing.

Here is Code:

```
-(void)shareFB:(NSString *)text
{
    if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {

        SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

        [controller setInitialText:text];

        [[CCDirector sharedDirector]presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Sorry!" message:@"Please add Facebook account in settings menu" delegate:Nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:Nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

It gives warning on :

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector]presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

That : **CCDirector may not respond to 'presentviewcontroller:animated:completion:'**

Comment: Is that working or is the app crashing

Comment: Yes it crashed.
Error : NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CCDirectorTimer presentViewController:animated:completion:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Please try the answer and let me know

Comment: Check my edit and let me know whether it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i got the solution .

My **`CCDirector`**  is *`NSObject`* type. I just change it to *`UIViewController`* and it works.
Thanks @Blisskarthik for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have edited your code with few corrections and pasted below. It's working fine

```
SLComposeViewController *faceBookPost = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

[faceBookPost setInitialText:@"I am playing game"];
[faceBookPost addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yourlink.com"]];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector]presentViewController:faceBookPost animated:YES completion:nil];
            faceBookPost.completionHandler = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result)
            {
                [[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];
                [[CCDirector sharedDirector] startAnimation];
                [[CCDirector sharedDirector]dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            };
```

Else Follow this step

Create an interface in your AppController with uinavigationcontroller like this

```
@interface MyNavigationController : UINavigationController <CCDirectorDelegate>
@end 

@interface AppController : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
UIWindow *window_;
MyNavigationController *navController_;
CCDirectorIOS   *director_;
}
```

In app controller's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions set the navigation controller

```
navController_ = [[MyNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:director_];
navController_.navigationBarHidden = YES;
[director_ setDelegate:navController_];
// set the Navigation Controller as the root view controller
[window_ setRootViewController:navController_];
```

Then in the class where you call SLComposeViewController present the view like this

```
 AppController *app = (AppController*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 [[app navController] presentViewController:faceBookPost animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Both type is working fine

Comment: Same warning on that line ,and same Error.